# Inverse of a Fractional Exponent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, exponentiation, fractions, inverse-function

Hello Mathematics Stack Exchange,

I'm currently a Grade $11$ Math Student and to train for this year's exam I am going through a worked video of the previous years' exams to get a better understanding of what to expect.

I came across the following question:

> $\text{Consider the function}:$
> $W=(x+2)^{\frac{2}{5}}$
> Make $x$ the subject of the formula.
> Seems pretty straightforward, right?

Well, this is the process they went through to isolate $x$:

$W=(x+2)^{\frac{2}{5}}$

$x+2=W^{\frac{5}{2}}$

$x=W^{\frac{5}{2}}-2$

So from what I can see, to get rid of the exponent $\frac25$ they raised the other side of the equation to the reciprocal which is $\frac52$. Now, I have searched online for 'inverse of a fractional exponent' etc, and I haven't really come across anything. Could someone explain to me more clearly *why* they raised it to the power of '$\frac52$'. I mean I am happy with accepting it as it is but I don't really know why they did this.

If there's something wrong with the question please let me know.

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: Recall that for positive reals $a$ you have that $(a^{b})^c = a^{(bc)}$, that $\frac{2}{5}\cdot \frac{5}{2}=1$ and that $a^1 = a$.  For a more advanced note, recognize that I insisted on $a$ being a positive real.  Be careful if the base is able to be negative or complex as the mentioned property may fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from the exponent rule: $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$. So if you want to "remove" an exponent, which means you're trying to get the final exponent to become $1$, you're trying to solve $ab = 1$ which means $b = \frac{1}{a}$. So if $a = \frac{2}{5}$, then $b = \frac{5}{2}$ meaning you have to raise everything to the power of $\frac{5}{2}$ to cancel out the power of $\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: My dad studied math in Uni and he's saying 'it's not possible' to do this... Weird, thanks for the answer; makes sense.

Comment: Note that if you have $y=x^\frac12$, then the inverse is not necessarily $y=x^2$, but rather $y=x^2,x\ge 0$. Also see [roots of complex numbers](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Extras/ComplexPrimer/Roots.aspx) which means that there are additional  answers possibly.